# Moving data from SQL Server 2008 to remote SQL Server 2000, using sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, sqlcmd

The setup:
I have two different machines, one with MS SQL Server 2008 which is my main machine and a secondary with MS SQL Server 2000. Newly generated data are stored in a specific table on the main server(2008).

The problem:
My main machine has limited storage, whereas my secondary one with the older SQL version(2000), doesn't have such kind of limitations.

A possible solution:
At least as a temporary solution, i could try to move some data, on a daily schedule, from the main machine to the secondary, using sqlcmd, run by a Windows Task Scheduler.
The largest portion of my data are stored on a single table so the idea is to "cut" them from the table on the main server and append them on a "backup/depot/storage" table on my secondary server.

What i have tried so far:
So far, i haven't been able to simultaneously connect to both servers from the main one, at least using sqlcmd. Is there a limitation for the sqlcmd to the connections it can create simultaneously?

Other possible ways:
Is there a suggested practice for that case? Would it be a good idea to write a vbs script to export from the main server and import to the secondary?

All corrections and suggestions are welcome. And thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you use a linked server? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: To be honest i haven't tried this. Does the linked server require a payed version of the MS SQL Server?

Comment: My suggestion is to use the linked server option too.  Link the servers, set up the password, and then you can simply so an INSERT to your backup server via a SELECT from your main server, and the SQL will operate as if everything's in the same place.  I do stuff like this all the time.

Comment: Ok i'm going to give it a try but how do i link the servers? Can i do it from the sqlcmd or do i have do try this from the MS SQL Studio? I it could be done from the sqlcmd could you please give me an example?

Comment: You create a linked server and then you just use it in sql as `[linkedservername].[databasename].[schema].[table]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, link the servers.  From the server you want to INSERT into, run this SQL (using any tool you want to run SQL with... SQL Server Management Studio or SQLCMD or OSQL or whatever):

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedServer N'remoteSqlServer\Instance', N'SQL Server'
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'remoteSqlServer\Instance', @useself = 'FALSE', @rmtuser = N'user', @rmtpassword = N'password'
```

Replace "remoteSqlServer\Instance" with the actual host-name\instance of the SQL Server you want to copy data FROM.  Also replace the "user" and "password" with appropriate login credentials to that server.

After that is done, you can execute SQL like the following against this server (from anywhere, including SQLCMD):

```
INSERT INTO [LocalTable]
SELECT * FROM [remoteSqlServer\Instance].[DatabaseName].[schema].[TableName]
```

Again, this is just an example... you'd replace all those values with values appropriate to your source and destination databases (everything in the square brackets).  For instance, it might look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [HistoricalData]
SELECT * FROM [DBServer\SQL2008].[ProductionDatabase].[dbo].[CurrentData]
```

I hope this helps.